# simpligility android-maven-plugin (4.3.0) -> duplicate manifest.mf

Tags: java, android, maven, jar, manifest.mf

I've got a big problem. I want to build an APK with a AAR-library (using normal JAR dependencies).

The AAR is build perfect with the JAR (not Android specific code, so it is used in normal Java project -> server side), but the APK wants to include the JAR-files as well. This is the expected behavior, because it needs all class files.

But then I received following error message at the end

**[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.simpligility.maven.plugins:android-maven-plugin:4.3.0:apk (default-apk) on project com.example.app: Duplicated file: MANIFEST.MF, found in archive ~/.m2/repository/com/example/shared/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/com.example.shared-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar and ~/.m2/repository/com/example/server/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/com.example.server-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar: Duplicate files at the same path inside the APK -> [Help 1]**

I'm also include

```
<configuration>
    <extractDuplicates>true</extractDuplicates>
</configuration>
```

but this does not remove double manifest.mf files. It only prints

**[ERROR] Cannot removing duplicates : duplicate entry: MANIFEST.MF**

Comment: you should post this on github

Comment: Also add this post to https://github.com/simpligility/android-maven-plugin/issues/665

Comment: Hi, Have you found any resolution to the issue? I'am having the same problem as yours:

Cannot removing duplicates : duplicate entry: about.html